# How to get and divide audio from an endless stream of audio

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, stream, wav

Firstly I have an endless cam stream which includes audio and video.

How to get divided .wav files according to time intervals from RTSP streaming while streaming.

[image: I want to]

I have tried the code below but I couldn't get the audio data before the stream ended

```html
command = ['ffmpeg.exe',
                   '-i', 'rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4',
                   '-f', 's16le',
                   '-acodec', 'libmp3lame',
                   '-ar', '44100',  
                   '-ac', '2', 
                   '-']
 
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE)

raw_audio = self.pipe.stdout.read()
print(raw_audio)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`-f segment`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) output container. Something like:

```py
command = ['ffmpeg.exe',
    "-i", r"rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4",
    '-vn', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '44100', '-ac', '2', 
    "-f", "segment", '-segment_time','3','out%03d.wav']
)
```

Now, if what you really need are the raw samples and not necessarily .wav files, you need to fix your command by removing the `'-acodec', 'libmp3lame'` option and specify the number of samples to read:

```
# how to read a block of audio data from stdout
n = 44100 * 3 # # of samples (sampling rate * duration)
nbytes = n * 2 * 2 # (#samples * #ch  * 2 bytes/sample)
while True:
    raw_audio = np.frombuffer(self.pipe.stdout.read(nread),shape=(n,2), dtype=np.int16)

    ... # do your thing
```